# Appkit standard colors

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nscolor

If there's way to get the standard system colors for UI element, such as default window background color ? There's no reference in the `NSWindow` documentation about any sort of constants or functions regarding color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not talking about the **System Colors** (class methods in `NSColor`), are you..?

- [`+ alternateSelectedControlColor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSColor/alternateSelectedControlColor)
- [`+ alternateSelectedControlTextColor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSColor/alternateSelectedControlTextColor)
- [`+ colorForControlTint:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSColor/colorForControlTint:)
- [`+ controlBackgroundColor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSColor/controlBackgroundColor)
- [`+ controlColor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSColor/controlColor)
- ...

Comment: concrete in this situation was an [NSColor windowBackgroundColor]

Comment: Sweet! Glad it helped

Answer (score 2):

Now Apple has dedicated manual page for this.

[UI Element Colors](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscolor/ui_element_colors)

- `windowBackgroundColor`
- `windowFrameTextColor`
- `underPageBackgroundColor`
- ...and so on.